# Unable to send mail in php not showing any error using mail()

Tags: php, email, gmail

Am trying to **send mail** using php `mail()` but its not showing any error or its been received in gmail. I am running this code on server :

```
  <?php
 // Multiple recipients
 $to = 'ram@gmail.com'; // note the comma

 // Subject
 $subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

  // Message
 $message = '
  <html>
 <head>
    <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
        </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Johny</td><td>10th</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
 </html>';


   // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
   $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
   $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

     // Additional headers
    $headers[] = 'To: ram <ram@gmail.com>';
    $headers[] = 'From: Birthday Reminder <admin@example.com>';
    echo $message;

      // Mail it
     mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
    ?>
```

Am using above code to send the mail to gmail but after running file I am not able to see any error nor the mail is received in gmail. I'm running code on server not in localhost.

Comment: *"not showing any error"* - that's because you never checked for them

Comment: Add this`';` after `<html>` tag

Comment: if you are running this exact code in server, then first end '; after </html>

Comment: @Mr.Developer I have added '; its same

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you please tell me how can I find errors as its not showing any errror while running code